# bash - running remote script from local machine

Tags: bash, shell

I tried this:

```
#!bin/bash
ssh user@host.com  'sudo /etc/init.d/script restart'
```

But I get this error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

How can I run that script? Now when I need to run that script I do these steps:

```
ssh user@host.com
sudo /etc/init.d/script restart
```

But I don't want to manually log in to remote server all the time and then enter restart command.

Can I write local script that I could run so I would only need to enter password and it would run remote script and restart the process?

Comment: Ask your sysadmin to give you the privilege to run `sudo /etc/init.d/script` without a password. If you're the sysadmin, see `man visudo` and `man sudoers`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-t` option in `ssh` command to **attach a pseudo-tty** with your `ssh` command:

```
ssh -t -t user@host.com 'sudo /etc/init.d/script restart'
```

As per `man ssh`:

> `-t     Force pseudo-tty allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.`

Comment: Today I noticed strange thing. When I execute that command from my local machine, I see normal message that remote server restarts and everything is fine, but actually that server goes down for some reason. If I restart normally from remote server, it restarts normally. Why could this happen?..

Comment: Oh and after using remote restart command, when I use that command directly from that server, it gives this message: `failed to kill 2190: No such process`. So for some reason it kills process instead of restarting.

Comment: I guess that `kiil` command would be part of your `/etc/init.d/script`