# bash remote command with sudo does not work

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've got this question answered here [bash - running remote script from local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644676/bash-running-remote-script-from-local-machine) about how could I use remote command with sudo involved. I thought it was working, because I got message that my server was successfully restarting etc so I chose answer. But today I saw that server actually was not restarting, but being killed for some reason.

Things I did, when I ran this command first time:

```
ssh user@host.com -t 'sudo /etc/init.d/script restart' #or -t just after ssh, same thing
```

I got this message:

```
Restarting openerp-server: Stopping openerp-server: openerp-server.
Starting openerp-server: openerp-server.
Connection to host.com closed.
```

So yeah, then I thought everything was good. But actually going to see if process restarted I saw it was not working.

And when I tried to restart again (with same command), I got this message:

```
Restarting openerp-server: Stopping openerp-server: start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 25205: No such process
openerp-server.
Starting openerp-server: openerp-server.
Connection to host.com closed.
```

But if I use same command when directly connected to remote server, everything works fine and my script restarts server normally.
Same command I mean this:

```
ssh user@host.com
sudo /etc/init.d/script restart
```

So what the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that the script that starts it up is doing something naughty that relies on the TTY staying alive briefly after the command returns. It is probably the immediate exit that is causing trouble. If it starts a background job that's attached to the shell inside the TTY, and detaches shortly afterwards, then closing the connection might kill the shell and kill the job inside it. That would explain why, when you restart, the script thinks there's a process number for the service, but then can't find it: maybe the process number gets logged somewhere, but then the process gets killed off before it can get going.

To confirm, you might try a couple of things. Log in remotely, run your `sudo` command, then exit immediately:

```
ssh user@host.com
sudo /etc/init.d/script restart; exit
```

and see if this immediate exit also hits the same problem.

Also try

```
ssh user@host.com -t 'sudo /etc/init.d/script restart; sleep 30'
```

to force it to wait for a bit, and see if that gets you anywhere.

Comment: The first option did run normally. It restarted normally even after exit. But using second option with sleep timer solved it. So I guess process of the restart took longer than actual connection to server when using remote command. Actually its even enough to put something like 1 second and it sill restarts normally